# Awesome nested set - wrong creating DB structure

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model, tree, nested-sets

I use this plugin for creating my tree structure. I have a little problem about my DB schema - I am not sure if it works well.
My DB table looks this:

```
+----+---------+-----------+------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | user_id | parent_id | lft  | rgt  | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+---------+-----------+------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |       2 |      NULL |    1 |    2 | 2011-11-25 18:48:14 | 2011-11-25 18:48:14 |
|  2 |       3 |         2 |    3 |   16 | 2011-11-25 18:49:07 | 2011-11-25 18:49:07 |
|  3 |       4 |         2 |    4 |    7 | 2011-11-25 18:50:56 | 2011-11-25 18:50:56 |
|  4 |       5 |         3 |    5 |    6 | 2011-11-25 18:56:37 | 2011-11-25 18:56:37 |
|  5 |       7 |         2 |    8 |    9 | 2011-11-28 08:44:11 | 2011-11-28 08:44:11 |
|  6 |       8 |         2 |   10 |   11 | 2011-11-28 10:56:26 | 2011-11-28 10:56:26 |
|  7 |       9 |         2 |   12 |   13 | 2011-11-28 16:57:54 | 2011-11-28 16:57:54 |
|  8 |      10 |         2 |   14 |   15 | 2011-11-29 14:01:45 | 2011-11-29 14:01:45 |
+----+---------+-----------+------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

I though the root item (with ID=1) will have automatically updated the values **lft** and **rgt**, but in my case not. I still don't know, what I am doing wrong.

Here is my procedure of creating items:

-creating node (root):

```
save_tree = TreeStruct.create!(:user_id => @user.id)
```

-creating item under the root item:

```
save_tree = TreeStruct.create!(:user_id => @user.id)
save_tree.move_to_child_of(params[:parent])
```

In the form where I create the items is the **hidden** input and this input have the value (ID) of root item.

My problem - what I am doing wrong, when I have still the value **lft=1** and **rgt=2** in the table? Shouldn't be the values there **1** and **16**?

Million times thanks for every help, I am really desperate from this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had to run *MyModel.rebuild!* after creating it. This seemed to redo all of the lft, rgt values etc.

You seem to also be able to run *rebuild* on an instance of a class with descendants. The documentation is fairly good, I solved most of my issues using the following cheat sheet:

https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set/wiki/Awesome-Nested-Set-Cheat-Sheet